# Restoring a React Context to its Default State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a React Context's default state as follows:

```
export const defaultState: UsersState = {
  isModalOpen: false,
  isCancelRequest: false,
  companyId: 0,
  users: []
};
```

When the modal it works with is cancelled, I want to clear the state back to the default.  This works:

```
    case RESET_STATE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isModalOpen: false,
        isCancelRequest: false,
        companyId: 0,
        users: []
      };
    }
```

But this does not:

```
    case RESET_STATE: {
      return {
        state: defaultState
      };
    }
```

When the context is first instantiated, this is what users looks like:

```
users: Array[0]
```

But when I use the latter, simplified approach to resetting the state, it looks like this:

```
users: Array  (empty)
```

At least, that's what I'm seeing in React DevTools.

Why does setting the `state` to `defaultState` not restore `users` to `Array[0]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `defaultState` instead of `{state: defaultState}`

like this.

```
    case RESET_STATE: {
      return defaultState;
    }
```

**Tutorial**

```js
const state = {
    isModalOpen: true,
    isCancelRequest: true,
    companyId: 123,
    users: ['1','2','3']
};

const defaultState: UsersState = {
  isModalOpen: false,
  isCancelRequest: false,
  companyId: 0,
  users: []
};

const getState1 = () => {
  return {
    ...state,
    isModalOpen: false,
    isCancelRequest: false,
    companyId: 0,
    users: []
  };
}

const getState2 = () => {
  return {
    state: defaultState
  };
}

const getState3 = () => {
  return defaultState;
}

console.log('this is goal state: ', getState1());
console.log('this is your state: ', getState2());
console.log('this is my state: ', getState3());
```

Comment: I have posted the tutorial. in this tutorial, you should see your mistake.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Conceptually I understand what you've written makes sense but unfortunately it doesn't work.  `users` does not end up as `Array[0]` but instead in this weird state of just `Array`  empty.  

I'll find another way to remove the contents of `users`.

Comment: Just spoke with a colleague.  I now realize that your approach is sound.  The problem is that the Reducer is a separate file which is referenced by the Context.  And the Reducer was importing `defaultState` from the Context.  Thus there's a bi-directional import occurring which seems to be causing the problem.

To solve this, I'll just explicitly reset each property in the Context back to its default value.  A bit of redundant code but at least it'll work properly.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
case RESET_STATE: {
      return {
        state: defaultState
      };
    }
```

should be:

```
case RESET_STATE: {
      return {
       ...defaultState
      };
    }
```

There's no object called `state`in your context